# Symfony 1.0 routing separators

Tags: symfony1, routes, separator, slash

I have used Symfony 1.4 before, but I'm maintaining an Symfony 1.0 project right now.

Basically, my question is about **routing** in **Symfony 1.0**:
**Is there a way to use anything else than slashes to separate variables?**

This works in both Symfony 1.0 and 1.4:

```
url: /:variable/:other_variable.html
```

This doesn't work in Symfony 1.0 (although it works in Symfony 1.4):

```
url: /:variable-:other_variable.html
```

The segment_separators option doesn't seem to exist in Symfony 1.0.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've been working with Symfony 1.0.x for several years now.  I have not seen segment_separators options, which I believe were introduced in 1.1.

Instead, you can treat the variables as a single variable/parameter and use a simple PHP [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)() call in your action to break them apart into respective variables.